# Is there a way that I can fix this cocoapods related error?

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

Thanks for reading my question.

I want to ask you why the error below is shown when I run my app!

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode... Running
> pod install... CocoaPods' output: ↳
> Preparing
>
> ```
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Inspecting targets to integrate
>   Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
>
> Finding Podfile changes
>   - Flutter
>   - audioplayers
>   - cloud_firestore
>   - firebase_analytics
>   - firebase_auth
>   - firebase_core
>   - google_sign_in
>   - path_provider_ios
>
> Fetching external sources
> -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
> -> Fetching podspec for `audioplayers` from `.symlinks/plugins/audioplayers/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
> cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
> -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
> firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
> -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
> firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
> -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
> firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
> -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
>
> Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
>   CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
>   CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
>   CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning
> ```
>
> local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.1.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists!
> Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
> CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning
> local because checking is only performed in repo update
> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
> In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
> Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.9.0)
>
> ```
>   In Podfile:
>     firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.11.0, which depends on
>       Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.10.0)
>
>
> You have either:
>  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
>  * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_core`.
>    You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.
>
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
> <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in
> ```
>
> `resolve' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in` resolve'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in
> `block in resolve_dependencies' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in
> `resolve_dependencies' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in` analyze'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in` resolve_dependencies'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in` run'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
> `run' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in` run'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in
> `<top (required)>' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in` load'
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `'
>
> Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy
> dependencies. To update the CocoaPods specs, run:   pod repo update
>
> Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro
> Max.

I know it's really long error.

As written above I've tried `pod repo update`, `pod install --repo-update` and `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly`.

everything doesn't fix this error.

So I tried reinstall cocoapods

and it's the latest version but still doesn't fix this error.

How can I fix this error?

If someone know about it, HELP ME PLEASE!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following command on the terminal

```
flutter clean
cd ios 
delete Pods
delete Podfile.lock
flutter pub get
pod install
flutter clean && flutter run
```

Comment: worked great, thank you. in my case 'delete Pods' and 'Delete Podfile.lock' did not work from command line (i believe i was in correct folder), but did work from finder.